# pdf 1.2: How to display a graphical image?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to learn structure of a pdf document from [guide](https://www.adobe.com/technology/pdfs/presentations/KingPDFTutorial.pdf). I could add the text and shapes with lines, but I am having problem displaying the image.

The code I am writing to display an image is (on page 54):

```
%PDF-1.2
% based on e08.pdf
1 0 obj
<<
    /Type /Page
    /Parent 5 0 R
    /Resources 3 0 R
    /Contents 2 0 R
>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<< /Length 51 >>
stream
    BT
        /F1 24 Tf
        1 0 0 1 260 254 Tm
        /CS1 cs
        63 127 127 sc
        (Hello World)Tj
    ET

    100 0 127 sc
    /CS2 CS
    0 0 1 SC
    315 226 m
    299 182 l
    339 208 l
    291 208 l
    331 182 l
    b
    100 0 0 100 65 326 cm
    BI /W 36 /H 32 /BPC 8
    /CS /DeviceGray
    ID
    ççççççççççççÕˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÕççççççççççç
    ççççççççççççÍˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÍçççççççççççç
    ççççççççççç¢ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ¢ççççççççççç
    ççççççççççç‘ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ‘ççççççççççç
    ççççççççççîˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇîçççççççççç
    ççççççççççøˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇøçççççççççç
    ççççççççççÒˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÒçççççççççç
    ççççççççç±ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ±ççççççççç
    ççççççççç€ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ€ççççççççç
    ççççççççõˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇõçççççççç
    ççççççççDˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇDçççççççç
    çççççççç¯ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ¯ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ¯çççççççç
    çççççççÕˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÕˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÕçççççç
    ççççççç‚ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÍçÍˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ‚ççççççç
    çççççç¢ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÕçÕˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ¢ççççç
    çççççç‘ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ¯ççç¯ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ‘çççççç
    çççççî¯ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇDçççÕˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ¯îççççç
    çççççøˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇõçççõˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇøççççç
    çççççÒˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ‘ççççç€ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÒççççç
    çççç™ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ™ççççç™ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ™ççç
    çççç‘ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÒçççççççÒˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ‘çççç
    çççõˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÕçççççççøˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇõççç
    çççDˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ¯îçççççççî¯ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇDççç
    çççÒˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÕççççççççç‘ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÒççç
    ççÕˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇõçççççççççõˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÕçç
    çç‚ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÒDDDDDDççççç‚ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ‚çç
    çõˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ™ççççÕˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇõç
    ç‘ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ‘çççççÒˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ‘ç
    î¯ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇîççççDˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ¯î
    ÕˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇøççççîˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÕ
    ÍˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÒççççç‘ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÒ
    ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ™çççç™ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ
    EI
endstream
endobj

3 0 obj
<<
    /ProcSet[/PDF/Text]
    /Font <</F1 4 0 R>>
    /ColorSpace
    <<
        /CS1 
            [ 
                /Lab 
                <<
                    /Range [-128 127 -128 127]
                    /WhitePoint [ 0.951 1 1.089]
                >> 
            ] 
        /CS2 
            [ 
                /CalRGB 
                    <<
                        /Gamma [2.222 2.222 2.222]
                        /Matrix 
                        [
                            0.412 0.213 0.019
                            0.358 0.715 0.119
                            0.181 0.072 0.951 
                        ]
                        /WhitePoint [0.951 1 1.089]
                    >> 
            ] 
    >>
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
    /Type /Font
    /Subtype /Type1
    /Name /F1
    /BaseFont/Helvetica
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
    /Type /Pages
    /Kids [ 1 0 R ]
    /Count 1
    /MediaBox [ 0 0 612 446 ] 
>>
endobj

6 0 obj
<<
    /Type /Catalog
    /Pages 5 0 R
>>
endobj

trailer
<< /Root 6 0 R >>
```

What I expect from it is:

[image: Desired result from my code]

But when I open the file in Acrobat Reader DC 2015, I see the text and the star, but not the image logo.

**Note:**

- I have formatted the code myself, so please let me know if it is not proper.
- I assume that there are problems with the characters that are used to show the Adobe logo. I guess the characters should be binary data, and when the PDF is generated, they are converted to those symbols.
- Here the author is using pdf 1.2, that is pretty old, but as far as I know it should not make a problem, since pdf is backward compatible.

**My question:**

- Why I cannot see the desired result as shown in the image using this code?
- How to get the codes needed to use in PDF to display an image. Let us say this textual representation of the binary code (or even the binary itself) that I have used in my code?

**Update:**

- As mentioned in the comment, cross reference table does not exist in my code, but when I generated that with *pdftk* tool, the result was the same.

Comment: Please supply the PDF as binary download. Textual representation of binary data tends to be destructive. Furthermore, I do not see any cross reference table in your file. Was that optional at the times of PDF 1.2?

Comment: I managed to get a bit further by (a) deleting extraneous `>>` `<<` pair before `/CS2` in `/Colorspace` resource definition (b) running through pdftk to reformat pdf and build cross reference like so: `pdftk musa.pdf output musa1.pdf`

Comment: @dwarring Thank you for your attention. I followed your steps, but still I cannot get the image displayed

Comment: @mkl Well I searched online for a while and did not find if XREF table was optional for 1.2, but strange thing is it works without that in other examples. Also I did not understand this part: "Please supply the PDF as binary download. Textual representation of binary data tends to be destructive."

Comment: @Musa without xref Adobe Reader tries to reconstruct that table upon loading the PDF which may or may not work. And what did you not understand about supplying the PDF as binary download?

Comment: @mkl The idea of the image and its data to be entered in the pdf is vague totally to me. You mentioned the "textual data", so is there an algorithm that converts the image binary data to the textual data, or the pure binary data was originally inserted to the as binary and in text editor it shows as text?

Comment: The problem is that you posted **binary data** (PDF is a binary data format even if it partially is defined via ASCII clear text sequences) as text. Thus, some character encoding has been applied, maybe several ones. If applied to originally binary data, such encoding can destroy the data as not every byte sequence is valid in a given encoding. But maybe this already is your problem, maybe the text representation of the PDF you posted makes sense if ancoded using Latin-1 but you saved it as UTF-8?

Comment: @mkl This is the binary download link to binary download: http://dev.midsserver.com:8080/temp/SO.pdf

I also tried Ansi, but no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***The major problem*** with your inline image is that you try to create a binary data block using text.

The data between **ID** and **EI** is interpreted as a stream of a single (!) white space character followed by *height x width x bits-per-component/8 x number-of-components* data bytes, i.e. in your case (according to `/W 36 /H 32 /BPC 8 /CS /DeviceGray`) 32 * 36 * 8/8 * 1 bytes.

This is not the case in your sample. In your question you have that data block indented which adds numerous bytes to the stream. Furthermore you have lines containing different numbers of bytes (even though they may look equally long in an editor).

Your binary download differs substantially from your question text, e.g. instead of the `ˇ` characters filling the *A* you have `.` characters there. If suffers from unequal line lengths, too

I assume you use a text editor to write that PDF which is a bad choice because you do not correctly see the real number of bytes used. Especially problematic are control characters and byte values not associated with a character in your encoding.

---

***Let's therefore try something more simple*** and only use characters in the ASCII range and a smaller, simpler form:

Depending on your end-of-line sequence (their bytes are part of the data bytes!!) use either of the following two samples

- in case of single byte end-of-line sequences (only CR or only LF, typical for Mac or Unix):

  ```
  BI /W 5 /H 4 /BPC 8
  /CS /DeviceGray
  ID
  zzzz
  z..z
  z..z
  zzzz
  EI
  ```
- in case of two byte end-of-line sequences (CR LF, typical for DOS / MS Windows):

  ```
  BI /W 6 /H 4 /BPC 8
  /CS /DeviceGray
  ID
  zzzz
  z..z
  z..z
  zzzz
  EI
  ```

**Do take care not to add any leading or trailing spaces!** They would also be interpreted as data bytes!

The result looks like this in the first case

[image: single byte line endings]

and this in the second case

[image: two byte line endings]

The dark bar(s) on the right / on both right and left is/are due to the line ending character(s).

If you don't want such bars, you have to get rid of the line endings, e.g.

```
BI /W 4 /H 4 /BPC 8
/CS /DeviceGray
ID zzzzz..zz..zzzzz EI
```

resulting in

[image: no line endings inbetween]

That all been said, please do yourself a favor and

- ***don't create PDFs as text***, e.g. in a text editor! While they can be understood to a certain degree in a text viewer, creating them in a text editor very soon becomes hell;
- ***don't use inline images*** but instead image resources! Inline images have proved to be troublesome and in PDF 2.0 will be deprecated or at least restricted to very small sizes; and finally
- ***don't use the PDF 1.2 reference*** but instead the current PDF standard [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)! Adobe personal called the old PDF references *not normative in nature*, so you can not count on what they say.

Comment: Thank you for all the time you have shared with me. One last question: you have mentioned "don't create PDFs as text, e.g. in a text editor!", so what do instead? If I want to create a PDF from scratch and using program code?

Comment: *so what do instead? If I want to create a PDF from scratch and using program code* - The in your code be sure not to construct the PDF as some `String` but instead some `byte[]` or `ByteBuffer`, and equivalently not using some text `Writer` but some binary `OutputStream`. Whereever you inject text, make sure you got your encoding right. In particular be aware that the encoding **WinAnsiEncoding** (often used for fonts in PDFs) is *not identical* to the ANSI encoding you have in Windows, merely very similar.

Comment: Better yet, make use of a PDF library that handles all this low-level stuff for you. Examples are [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) and [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) for PHP, or [iText](http://itextpdf.com) and [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org) for Java.

Comment: Yes indeed, one really should use existing PDF libraries. But before committing to one such library one should check its quality. There are libraries that internally create a PDF inside a `StringBuffer` which results in problems after problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem working a text editor like Windows NotePad **as long as you stick to the rules of PDF structures**.

The Whole file is Binary Bytes as a stream thus must be edited as ANSI not ASCII or UTF-8 which PDF did/does not generally use for text formatting. NO file BOMs, they are only used for some string encodings.

as @MKL points out, NO Indents nor LineFeeds in text nor image streams.
Greyscale images should be PGM format.
Note the copy and paste to  or from HTML may not work well, here is the source image 35x32 saved as BGP and as pasted into NotePad but there are characters missing here in paste to HTML !

```
100 0 0 100 65 326 cm
BI /W 35 /H 32 /BPC 8 /CS/G /D[0 1]
ID
»ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ»ëÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿë£ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ£ÕÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÕ•ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ•»ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ»ñÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿñ±ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ±ÛÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÛ›ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ›ÇÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÇùÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿùÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿù»ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ»ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ»ãÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿëëÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿã£ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ»»ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ£ÕÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿùùÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÕ•ùÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÇÍÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿù•»ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ››ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ»ñÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÕÛÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿñ«ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ««ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ«ÕÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿññÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÕ›ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ»»ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ›Çÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿù••ùÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÇñÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÍÕÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿñ»ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ››ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ»ãÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿñÇÇÇÇÇÇãÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿã›ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ«»ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ›ÕÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÕñÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÕ•ùÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ•Çÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿù•»ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ»•ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ»ëÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿñÕÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿñÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ««ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
EI
```

[image]

You can even use RGB for Monochrome:-) if you want to "Big it up"

[image]